# How do you check what version of SQL Server for a database using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Is there a system stored procedure to get the version #?

Comment: http://blog.devstone.com/aaron/default,date,2006-12-15.aspx

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

or for SQL Server 2000 and above the following is easier to parse :)

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')
     , SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel')
     , SERVERPROPERTY('edition')
```

From: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Comment: The second one works for me, and i add to check on Wikipedia to understand that 8.00.xx means SQL server 2000

Answer (score 31):

SELECT @@VERSION

Answer (score 29):

I know this is an older post but I updated the code found in the [link](http://blog.devstone.com/aaron/default,date,2006-12-15.aspx) (which is dead as of 2013-12-03) mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59450/15168) posted by [Matt Rogish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2590/matt-rogish):

```
DECLARE @ver nvarchar(128)
SET @ver = CAST(serverproperty('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar)
SET @ver = SUBSTRING(@ver, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @ver) - 1)

IF ( @ver = '7' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 7'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '8' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2000'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '9' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2005'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '10' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2008/2008 R2'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '11' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2012'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '12' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2014'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '13' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2016'
ELSE IF ( @ver = '14' )
   SELECT 'SQL Server 2017'
ELSE
   SELECT 'Unsupported SQL Server Version'
```

Answer (score 14):

For SQL Server 2000 and above, I prefer the following parsing of Joe's answer:

```
declare @sqlVers numeric(4,2)
select @sqlVers = left(cast(serverproperty('productversion') as varchar), 4)
```

Gives results as follows:

```
Result   Server Version
8.00     SQL 2000
9.00     SQL 2005
10.00    SQL 2008
10.50    SQL 2008R2
11.00    SQL 2012
12.00    SQL 2014
```

Basic list of version numbers [here](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/), or exhaustive list from Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185?wa=wsignin1.0).

Comment: I like this, nice, simple and resusable across server versions. I used a slightly modified version of the above: `select cast(serverproperty('productversion') as varchar) as [result]`. My point is that I can execute the above via ADO.NET's `ExecuteScalar` and then parse the result string as a `System.Version` object. Also, conveting it into numeric gives different meanings to version numbers when it comes to trailing zeros and version segment digit count, while a string can be parsed to a valid `Version` object without losing the consistency of each version component.

Answer (score 4):

There is another extended Stored Procedure which can be used to see the Version info:

```
exec [master].sys.[xp_msver]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UFN_GET_SQL_SEVER_VERSION 
(
)
RETURNS sysname
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ServerVersion sysname, @ProductVersion sysname, @ProductLevel sysname, @Edition sysname;

    SELECT @ProductVersion = CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')), 
           @ProductLevel = CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel')),
           @Edition = CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY ('Edition'));
    --see: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/321185
    SELECT @ServerVersion = 
        CASE 
            WHEN @ProductVersion LIKE '8.00.%' THEN 'Microsoft SQL Server 2000'
            WHEN @ProductVersion LIKE '9.00.%' THEN 'Microsoft SQL Server 2005'
            WHEN @ProductVersion LIKE '10.00.%' THEN 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008'
            WHEN @ProductVersion LIKE '10.50.%' THEN 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2'
            WHEN @ProductVersion LIKE '11.0%' THEN 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012'
            WHEN @ProductVersion LIKE '12.0%' THEN 'Microsoft SQL Server 2014'
        END

    RETURN @ServerVersion + N' ('+@ProductLevel + N'), ' + @Edition + ' - ' + @ProductVersion;

END
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of script I use for testing if a server is 2005 or later

```
declare @isSqlServer2005 bit
select @isSqlServer2005 = case when CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(15), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 0, CHARINDEX('.', CONVERT(varchar(15), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))))) < 9 then 0 else 1 end
select @isSqlServer2005
```

Note : updated from original answer (see comment)

Comment: Just found this doesn't work sql 2008 because '10' is less than '9'.
You can change the value in the updated answer to use 8, 9, 10 or whatever you need to test as a minimum value

Answer (score 2):

The KB article linked in [Joe's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59444/how-do-you-check-what-version-of-sql-server-for-a-database-using-tsql#59457) is great for determining which service packs have been installed for any version.  Along those same lines, [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937137) maps version numbers to specific hotfixes and cumulative updates, but it only applies to SQL05 SP2 and up.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT @@MICROSOFTVERSION / 0x01000000 AS MajorVersionNumber
```

For more information see: [Querying for version/edition info](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/783.sql-server-versions.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (SELECT LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as varchar), 2)) = '10'
BEGIN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
@@SERVERNAME AS ServerName,
CASE WHEN LEFT(CAST(serverproperty('productversion') as char), 1) = 9 THEN '2005'
 WHEN LEFT(CAST(serverproperty('productversion') as char), 2) = 10 THEN '2008'
 WHEN LEFT(CAST(serverproperty('productversion') as char), 2) = 11 THEN '2012'
END AS MajorVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') AS MinorVersion, 
SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS FullVersion, 
SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') AS Edition
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting only the major SQL Server version in a single select:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(ver, 1, CHARINDEX('.', ver) - 1)
FROM (SELECT CAST(serverproperty('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar) ver) as t
```

Returns `8` for SQL 2000, `9` for SQL 2005 and so on (tested up to 2012).

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the major version for T-SQL reasons, the following gives you the year of the SQL Server version for 2000 or later.

`SELECT left(ltrim(replace(@@Version,'Microsoft SQL Server','')),4)`

This code gracefully handles the extra spaces and tabs for various versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring(@@version,0,charindex(convert(varchar,SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')) ,@@version)+len(convert(varchar,SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT @@VERSION[server], SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    'the sqlserver is ' + substring(@@VERSION, 21, 5) AS [sql version]
```