# SQL Server data extraction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am doing automation of security bulleting of SQL Server and I need to extract security bulletin version from `@@version`

```
select @@version
```

Output

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64) 
Jun 17 2016 19:14:09 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I need to extract information (KB3171021) from above output.

This is something I tried

```
DECLARE @version NVARCHAR(400)

SELECT @version = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@@version, 0, 50))

SELECT @version

SELECT SUBSTRING(@version, (CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@@VERSION))),(CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE(@@VERSION))))
```

I am not getting desired output. Can you please help?

Comment: try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59457), you would need to change parameters

Comment: [The @@version might not contain it at all...](http://rextester.com/CCDBE39117)

Comment: True that, i am getting `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - ...`

Comment: @zohar @@version has all info you just have to extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As I've shown in the link to rextester in my comment, the `@@version` might not contain the data you are looking for.

You might also want to check out [`SERVERPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql)

However, if your systems will always contain it, the simplest way to extract it would be to get the data inside the second parenthesis:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  CHARINDEX('(', @@Version, CHARINDEX('(', @@Version) + 1) As SecondOpen,
            CHARINDEX(')', @@Version, CHARINDEX(')', @@Version) + 1) As SecondClose
)

SELECT  SUBSTRING(@@Version, SecondOpen + 1, SecondClose - SecondOpen - 1)
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
KB3171021
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/NKNLP46989)

Comment: yes but when iam using this  SELECT  @@Version As Original,
            SUBSTRING(@@Version, CHARINDEX('(', @@Version, (CHARINDEX('(', @@Version) + 1)) +1,(CHARINDEX('(', @@Version, CHARINDEX('(', @@Version) + 1) - CHARINDEX(')', @@Version, CHARINDEX(')', @@Version)) + 1) -1) As KB,
            @@Version As ActualVersion its not giving me result , i just combined everything in 1 query